# Probability unif

Tags: uniform-distribution

By the Central Limit Theorem, I am asked estimate the probability that P$\leq\ $$\mathsf E(P)$.
The answer of 50% is what I am getting but this seems incorrect and can't seem to convince myself otherwise. If anyone could shed some light on this as to why this incorrect or even how to think about this problem properly, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The central limit theorem ends up with a normal distribution, which is symmetric around the mean, so the probability of being less than the mean is 50%.  Why do you think it is incorrect?

Comment: @user12321 See my answer

Comment: @herbsteinbergThe clt does not say the distribution of a product of RVs is normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the CLT on a product, take logs. $\log(P)=\sum_{i=1}^5\log(X_i).$ So by the CLT (if $5$ were a lot larger), $P$ would be a log-normal.

So the question is what is the probability for a log-normal to be less than its mean, which is not $50\%$. Looking up the relevant stuff for the standard parametrization on wikipedia, $$ P(X\le E(X)) = \int_0^{e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}} \frac{1}{x\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(\log(x)-\mu)^2} = \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{\sigma}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-u^2/2}du = \Phi(\sigma/2).$$ So it's going to depend on the variance of $\log(X)$.

Comment: What was the u-substitution you used?

Comment: @user12321 yep, that's right. The u substitution for integrating it? $u = (\log(x)-\mu)/\sigma.$

Comment: Just to be clear, what is going to depend on log(X), $$ P(P\le E(P))$$

Comment: Okay, it's just that I haven't used the lognormal very often, so I was unaware of the correct u-substitution. Thank you.

Comment: @user12321 For $P$ log-normal, $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are the mean and std dev of $\log(P),$ where $\log(P)$ is normal. So (assuming, dubiously for a skewed distribution with $n=5,$ the central limit theorem), we have $\sigma^2 = nVar(\log(X)).$

Comment: @user12321 actually, looking at the distribution of $\log(X)$ it isn't very skewed, so this approximation probably does ok

Comment: now all I have to do is find the variance of ln(X), multiply it by 5 and find the corresponding value from the normal distribution table?

Comment: @user12321 yep (well, to be fully specific you also need to take the square root of that and then divide by 2 before plugging into the CDF. )

Comment: yep that's what I was intending on doing. This was very helpful.

Comment: I just also wanted to ask if this problem could be solved by standardizing the variables. So that (lnP-mu)/(5var(ln(X)^.5). Where mu is equal to 5 times the mean of each ln(X)?

Comment: @user12321 I don't see how that would help. While the standardized form $Z=\frac{\log(P)-5E(\log X )}{\sqrt{5Var(\log(X))}}$ has a nice (approximately) N(0,1) distribution,  but you eventually want to know about something in terms of $P.$ You could express $P$ as $Ae^{bZ}$ for some $A$ and $b,$ compute $E(Ae^{bZ})=E(P)$ and then write $P(P<E(P)) = P(Z<\log(E(P)/A)/b) = \Phi(\log(E(P)/A)/b).$ That's pretty much doing the same thing we did and doesn't strike me as any easier.

Comment: @user12321 I guess perhaps using the mean of the lognormal might have been a bit a bit mysterious. When you compute $E(e^{bZ})$ in the above steps (by completing the square) you are effectively doing that by hand.